# How to set picklist options in a flow's UI using values retrieved from a callout

Tags: visual-workflow, callout, picklist

I would like to make a callout using Apex and use the return data to set the options in a picklist screen component of a flow. Is this possible and if yes, how should I go about it (I believe I need to create 1) an Apex-defined collection variable to hold the return data and 2) a choices variable to populate the picklist. However, I cannot seem to find a way to set the `Choice` Value attribute of the `Choice` variable to a value from the collection variable)

Follow-up: I found how to set the value of a Choice resource using the return data but unfortunately it is impossible to create a collection variable of type `Choice` with which you can then populate a picklist using the standard flow builder functionality  at the moment. You would have to create individual variables of type `Choice` and manually add them as picklist choices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Choice resource is limited in its application and can't do what you want. However, the [Quick Choice](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/) component can be installed and will happily accept a couple of string collections (one for the values and one for the labels) returned by your Apex invocable action

Comment: Glad to know there are some workarounds out there.